# How to define a function containing integrals?

Tags: matlab, plot, numerical-integration

I am trying to create the following function in MATLAB to be used for plotting (see image)
[image]

Here is the function I have:

```
function M = diodeMultiplication(alpha, beta, x, w)

M = (exp(-int(alpha-beta,x,w)))./(1-(int(alpha.*exp(-int(alpha-beta,diff(x),w)),0,w));

end
```

Where x is a constant (I.e. x = 0) and w is a constant (I.e. w = 1.*10^-4) and alpha and beta are arrays of floating point values that are functions of E.

I would like to input alpha,beta, x and w and plot E vs M. which would look something like this:

```
plot(E, diodeMultiplication(alpha, beta, x, w));
```

This function will not run. Does anyone have any input?

Comment: "The function does not run" - could you [edit] your question to include a specific error message? Currently this is too broad, you're asking for debugging help without a [mcve] or enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.int.html) the first input of `int` is a symbolic expression not an array. If you want to compute a numerical integration you can estimate your integral with `trapz` (or another numerial integration function). For the moment your example is incomplete, what is `E`, `alpha` and `beta` ? Provide an example input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to do a numerical integration, so use `integral` instead of `int`.

You will also need to define `alpha` and `beta` as functions to do so. This is done by just giving `alpha` as the function that computes the array you mentioned, e.g. if `alpha=E.^2` then instead of that, you input `alpha=@(x)(x.^2)` to `integral`.